How to define return type for extension in SwiftUI?
This is my extension:
extension Image {
    func centerCropped() -> some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            self
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFill()
                .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height)
            .clipped()
        }
    }
}

and this is how I use it:
Image(url: url, key: key)
    .centerCropped()
    .widgetAccentedRenderingMode(.accentedDesaturated) // ❌ Value of type 'some View' has no member 'widgetAccentedRenderingMode'

How can I define it properly here? All I need is to support accented images for iOS 18 widgets.

How about just changing the order of the modifiers?

doeznt work also... then there is issue Value of type 'some View' has no member 'centerCropped'.

So try making it an extension to View? Alternatively, apply .widgetAccentedRenderingMode inside the modifier?

When I make an extension to View then .resizable() doesnt exist for View. It is only for Image. I cannot add it inside modifier because it breaks some rules;)

Try to create view modifier
struct CenterCropped: ViewModifier {

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            content
                .scaledToFill()
                .frame(
                    width: geo.size.width,
                    height: geo.size.height
                )
                .clipped()
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    func centerCropped() -> some View {
        modifier(CenterCropped())
    }
}

BUT use .resizable() on a image itself, because default view can't be resized
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Image("someImage")
            .resizable()
            .widgetAccentedRenderingMode(.fullColor)
            .centerCropped()
            
    }
}


The issue here is that .resizable and .widgetAccentedRenderingMode both require an Image, whereas View modifiers like .scaledToFill and .clipped return some View.
So you basically have two options:

Define the extension on View and apply the Image operations separately (before applying your extension). This is illustrated in the other answer.

Or... define the extension on Image and apply all the modifiers in one place.


The choice of approach might depend on whether you expect to be using the modifier for any kind of View that is not an Image. If so, you would go for approach 1. But since the modifier is applying .scaledToFill, I would think it is very likely that it will only be used for images.
So here is how you could implement it the second way. You might like to allow the rendering mode to be passed as parameter, with default of nil to make it more general-purpose.
While we're at it, you could also consider a different way of clipping the image, by showing it as an overlay over Color.clear. It's perhaps a bit simpler than using a GeometryReader.
import WidgetKit

extension Image {
    func centerCropped(renderingMode: WidgetAccentedRenderingMode? = nil) -> some View {
        Color.clear
            .overlay {
                self
                    .resizable()
                    .widgetAccentedRenderingMode(renderingMode)
                    .scaledToFill()
            }
            .clipped()
            // .ignoresSafeArea() // Could add this modifier too
    }
}

Example usage:
Image(.image1)
    .centerCropped(renderingMode: .accentedDesaturated)

